# Is it possible to display a View written with SwiftUI with NativeScript

Tags: swift, nativescript

I'm currently using native Swift code via the bridging header, but not to something like a View.  Is it possible to present a View written in Swift from some event trigger within nativescript code?

Comment: Yes, you can present a native view controller in NativeScript. Lot of plugins does it already, but you may have to make sure your [swift apis meets the requirements here](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#apis-written-in-swift)